# Putting a custom UIView at the bottom of a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar

I want to write a table view that lists expenses.  At the top of the table view I'd like a navigation bar to show a little bar that visually demonstrates how much of the budget has been spent (see image). The lower portion of that navigation bar will be a custom `UIView`.

How do I modify the `UINavigationBar` to include this custom view?  Is that even the right thing to do?  Should I write the top portion of that image as a custom `UIView` complete with buttons or will that be rejected because I'm reimplementing a standard view?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be rejected if you build your own custom view.

You can set UINavigationItem's titleView property as seen in the docs here
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html
Personally, I would build this as a custom view and recreate your own back button functionality.