# How to constrain a view to the bottom left of a UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, constraints

My goal is to add a logo to the bottom left corner of a UINavigationBar, and to add constraints so that it stays there upon rotation.

Here's what I've tried:

```
UIView* navBarView = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
UIImageView* logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"asdf"]];

[navBarView addSubview:logoImageView];

NSLayoutConstraint *logoConstraintLeftAlign =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:logoImageView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:navBarView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                multiplier:1.0f
                                  constant:0.0f];

NSLayoutConstraint *logoConstraintBottomAlign =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:logoImageView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:navBarView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                multiplier:1.0f
                                  constant:0.0f];

[navBarView addConstraint:logoConstraintLeftAlign];
[navBarView addConstraint:logoConstraintBottomAlign];
```

But that produces errors regarding some conflicting constraints:

```
2013-10-17 13:34:07.202 WTTest6[6551:a0b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13196350 UIImageView:0x13198280.bottom == UINavigationBar:0x9d98970.bottom>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1318a6c0 h=--& v=--& UIImageView:0x13198280.midY == + 12>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1318a6f0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIImageView:0x13198280(24)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x131aa0e0 h=-&- v=--& V:[UINavigationBar:0x9d98970(44)]>"
```

`Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13196350 UIImageView:0x13198280.bottom == UINavigationBar:0x9d98970.bottom>`

I looked at the refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints, but was a bit overwhelmed by it, as I am just working with constraints for the first time.

I tried setting the frame of the logoImageView, which worked for the default orientation. I suppose I'd have to change the frame each time the orientation changes. But that seems contrary to the point of using AutoLayout and constraints.

So my question is, Can I use constraints to anchor the view like I want, and if so, how do I avoid the NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint "problem"?

Note that I looked at [Putting a custom UIView at the bottom of a UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333518/putting-a-custom-uiview-at-the-bottom-of-a-uinavigationbar) but that suggested using the titleView of the UINavigationBarItem, which is centered, and thus does not help with the left alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, what I found is that basically ANY time I add a constraint to something and I get conflicts, it's because I did NOT add this to the object I am adding the constraint to:

```
[someUIView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

DO NOT put this on the container view, just the subViews.

Comment: It looks like that will prove valuable in general, but in the case of the UINavigationBar, setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO on one of it's subviews results in an Assertion failure and crash. I can add a subview to UINavigationBar, and then add my logoImageView to that with translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO. That results in the constraints working correctly within the first subview. But I don't have control over where UINavigationBar puts that first subview, which defeats the point of the whole exercise.

Comment: You should not be setting that or constraints on the UINavigationBar if your view is in a navigation controller. The controller will handle that part. You just need to worry about the views you add as subviews.

Comment: To clarify, I first added logoImageView as a subview of UINavigationBar. Then set [logoImageView translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]. That resulted in the Assertion failure and crash.

Comment: Using constraints in there might be tough. You might be able to trick it by making it an image button and using those old properties for right bar button, etc. Or chuck the navigation bar it manages and make your own tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

Set 'autoresizingMask' on 'navigationBar' subviews for your layout.
keep setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES on all subviews.

It works for me.